# Change composite Primary Key effect on update performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I changed one field on a primary key on a **SQL Server 2012** table. I removed one field of the 11 in the composite primary key and replaced it with a field of the same datatype and size.

Updating 45,000 records in this table used to take seconds and now it takes 45 minutes. Actually I updated 3 almost exact tables and am seeing the same effect in all the tables.

What could have slowed down the updates?

Comment: `I removed one field of the 11 in the composite primary key` : that is a large key you've got there...

Comment: Show "before" and "after" DDL scripts of your table. And update statement.

Comment: These issues are almost always either a missing index or bad statistics. Because of what you did, it could easily be either or both. Also, are you clustering on the PK columns?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't add comments.

Did you completely re-create the Index (DROP & CREATE)? If so did you change settings such as SORT IN TEMP DB?

When you UPDATE the table are you updating the field that has been added to the INDEX?

Have you checked for Fragmentation?